# ActionScript 3 error Invalid JSON parse input

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to send data to a PHP file via JSON but i'm getting an error when trying to JSON the data.

I'm pretty sure i'm doing this right. Any suggestions ?

Here's my ActionScript 3 code :

```
var dataToSend:Array = new Array();

var data:Object = new Object(); 
    data.callFunction = "getQuestion";  
    data.numberOfQuestions = "1";   

dataToSend.push(data);

trace(data);

var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();    
    variables.data = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);

var url:String = "myurl";

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);   
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
    request.data = variables;    

var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(); 
    loader.load(request);   
    loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, requestComplete);
```

And my PHP code :

```
if $data[ "callfunction" ] = "getQuestion";
{
    echo("Sent");
}
```

Comment: Do you get the error on the php side or in As3? What does the php file look like? What json is it expecting?

Comment: Thanks for your response, not getting any errors on the php side just as3. I've added my php code. Would you mind taking a look please ?

Comment: I have no idea about php and cannot comment on that. Are you sure the error JSON **parse** input is caused by the As3 code above? You are not calling `JSON.parse()` in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your ActionScript 3 code looks fine but you have some problems in your PHP's one.

Let's see that.

- 1. The [`if`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) statement in PHP is like the AS3's one :

```
<?php
    if( condition )
        instruction;
?>
```

- 2. The [equality operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) is the `==` and not the [assignment](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) one ( `=` ).
- 3. As you have sent your data using the `POST` method, you can use the PHP's [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) array to get it.
- 4. Then, as you have sent it on JSON format, you can decode it using the [`decode_json()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function in your PHP side.

So your PHP code can be like this for example :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['data']))
    {
        $data = $_POST['data'];
        $json_data = json_decode($data);        

        if($json_data[0]->callFunction == "getQuestion")
        {
            echo("Sent");
        }
    }

?>
```

Then  you can get the response of your PHP script in your AS3 `requestComplete` function :

```
function requestComplete(e:Event): void 
{
    trace(URLLoader(e.target).data);    // gives : Sent, for example
}
```

...

Hope that can help.